# Terraform with AWS Beanstalk not deploying application version

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

While creating an Elastic Beanstalk app using terraform, everything deploys fine except my application version is not being deployed to environment. When I manually deploy that version using console, it works. Application version is within encrypted S3 bucket using KMS.
This is my terraform configuration:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "beanstalk_app" {
  name        = "app-test"
  description = "Test java app"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "beanstalk_app_version" {
  name        = "app-test-version-label"
  application = "app-test"
  description = "application version created by terraform"
  bucket      = aws_s3_bucket.app.id
  key         = aws_s3_object.upload_app.id
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalk_env" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_db_instance.education,
    aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version.beanstalk_app_version
  ]
  name                = "test-environment"
  application         = "app-test"
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2023 v4.0.0 running Corretto 17"
  tier = "WebServer"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "VPCId"
    value     = data.aws_vpc.default_vpc.id
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value     =  "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "AssociatePublicIpAddress"
    value     =  "True"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "Subnets"
    value     = join(",", data.aws_subnets.default_subnet.ids)
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
    name      = "MatcherHTTPCode"
    value     = "200"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
    name      = "LoadBalancerType"
    value     = "application"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "InstanceType"
    value     = "t3.micro"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "ELBScheme"
    value     = "internet facing"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MinSize"
    value     = 1
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MaxSize"
    value     = 2
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system"
    name      = "SystemType"
    value     = "enhanced"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_HOST"
    value     = aws_db_instance.education.address
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_NAME"
    value     = aws_db_instance.education.db_name
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_PORT"
    value     = aws_db_instance.education.port
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_USER"
    value     = aws_db_instance.education.username
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_PASSWORD"
    value     = aws_db_instance.education.password
  }
}
```

Environment console view

[image]

Then after manually deploying:

[image]

It works:

[image]

I followed terraform documentation regarding Beanstalk configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the [`version_label`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_environment#version_label) is missing in the `aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment` resource definition. The documentation says it is optional, but since you need it you will have to specify it:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "beanstalk_app" {
  name        = "app-test"
  description = "Test java app"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "beanstalk_app_version" {
  name        = "app-test-version-label"
  application = "app-test"
  description = "application version created by terraform"
  bucket      = aws_s3_bucket.app.id
  key         = aws_s3_object.upload_app.id
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "beanstalk_env" {
  name                = "test-environment"
  application         = "app-test"
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2023 v4.0.0 running Corretto 17"
  tier                = "WebServer"
  version_label       = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version.beanstalk_app_version.name

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "VPCId"
    value     = data.aws_vpc.default_vpc.id
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value     =  "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "AssociatePublicIpAddress"
    value     =  "True"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "Subnets"
    value     = join(",", data.aws_subnets.default_subnet.ids)
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default"
    name      = "MatcherHTTPCode"
    value     = "200"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
    name      = "LoadBalancerType"
    value     = "application"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "InstanceType"
    value     = "t3.micro"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:ec2:vpc"
    name      = "ELBScheme"
    value     = "internet facing"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MinSize"
    value     = 1
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MaxSize"
    value     = 2
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system"
    name      = "SystemType"
    value     = "enhanced"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_HOST"
    value     = aws_db_instance.education.address
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_NAME"
    value     = aws_db_instance.education.db_name
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_PORT"
    value     = aws_db_instance.education.port
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_USER"
    value     = aws_db_instance.education.username
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_PASSWORD"
    value     = aws_db_instance.education.password
  }
}
```

Additionally, when using implicit dependencies between resources (e.g., referencing the RDS information using the `aws_db_instance.education.<attribute>` syntax, you don't need the `depends_on` block. The same applies for the application version label, as terraform will know it needs to create the application version label prior to creating/updating the environment resource.